# How to inspect every query going to DB from Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select, zend-db-profiler

I have a complex reporting application that allows clients to login and view reports for their client data. There are several sections of the application where there are database calls, using various controllers. I need to make sure that client A doesn't get client B's information via header manipulation.

The system authenticates, and assignes them a clientID and roleID. If your roleID >1, that means you work for the company hosting the data, and you can see all client info. I want to create a catch-all that basically works like this:

```
    if($roleID > 1) {

    ...send query to database

   }else {
     if(...does this query select a record with clientID other than my $auth->clientID){
     do not execute query
  }else {
   execute query
   }
}
```

The problem is, I want this to run for every query that goes to the server... how can I place this code as a "roadblock" between the application and the DB? I already use Zend_Profiler to look at queries, so I know it is somehow possible, but cannot discern this from the Profiler code...

I can always write an authentication function and pass selected queries that way, but this catch-all would be easier to implement across all of the calls and would be future proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tend to use ZFdebug toolbar , its very helpfull [Database: Full listing of SQL queries and the time for each] http://jokke.dk/software/zfdebug

Answer (score 1):

it's application design fault. 
you shoud use 'service architecture' - the only one entry point for queries would be a `service`. and any checks inside it.

Comment: not sure I understand... i thought Zend Framework was acting as a pseudo - service?

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you want run on *every* query, I'd suggest extending `Zend_Db_Select` and overwrite either the `query()` or `assemble()` functions to add in your logic. You'll also want to add a way for it to be aware of your `$auth` object.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to extend your database adapter so you can intercept the queries directly. IMO, you should try and do this at the application level though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database server, you can put a trace on the DB side.

Here's an example for Oracle:

http://orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace